# Add an index column in csv file

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

l have the following sample to transform. After concatenating several csv files l keep the index of each row 0 up to last row of the file in each file as depicted below.

```
    Column_1    column2
0   m            4
1   n            3
2   4            6
3   t            8
0   h            8
1   4            7
2   kl           8
3   m            4
4   bv           5
5   n            8
```

Now l want to add another column in the beginning indexing the file.

```
        Column_1    column2
0   0   m           4
1   1   n           3
2   2   4           6
3   3   t           8
4   0   h           8
5   1   4           7
6   2   kl          8
7   3   m           4
8   4   bv          5
9   5   n           8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpliest is [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) by [`numpy.arange`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) or `range`:

```
print (np.arange(len(df.index)))
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]

n = ['a','b']
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([np.arange(len(df.index)), df.index], names= n)
print (df)
    Column_1  column2
a b                  
0 0        m        4
1 1        n        3
2 2        4        6
3 3        t        8
4 0        h        8
5 1        4        7
6 2       kl        8
7 3        m        4
8 4       bv        5
9 5        n        8
```

```
n = ['a','b']
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([range(len(df.index)), df.index], names= n)
print (df)
    Column_1  column2
a b                  
0 0        m        4
1 1        n        3
2 2        4        6
3 3        t        8
4 0        h        8
5 1        4        7
6 2       kl        8
7 3        m        4
8 4       bv        5
9 5        n        8
```

If index names are not necessary, simply assign:

```
df.index = [np.arange(len(df.index)), df.index]
print (df)
    Column_1  column2
0 0        m        4
1 1        n        3
2 2        4        6
3 3        t        8
4 0        h        8
5 1        4        7
6 2       kl        8
7 3        m        4
8 4       bv        5
9 5        n        8
```

Comment: Hmmm, some problem?